# Calling db2 function from db connector in IBM Datastage

Tags: datastage

I would like to create job:

SourceFile -> Transformer -> Lookup connected to DB connector (Lookup Sparse) -> Peek

SourceFile contains dates (string format). In Transformer I've added InputDate with input dates, SourceT and TargetT with some hardcoded parameters. I would like to call

```
select Function(to_date(Value1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), Value2, Value3) from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

where values: Value1,2,3 are the transferred from Transformer (Value1=Inputdate, Value2=SourceT and Value3=TargetT ) to DB connector and results of query are transferred to Peek. I can do this using DB2 stored procedure but at this moment it is not possible. I would like to call the function as many times as I have InputDate values in source file.

I tried do this using lookup sparse but still does not work.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Describe what you mean with "does not work" - what is the problem? Which error is returned? What happens?

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher , to clarify....The Transformer is currently connected to Lookup stage. I'm using lkp sparse type connecting to db2 database. In the db2 connector I'm using my user privileges to connect to db2 instance. In the SELECT field I try to call a scalar db2 function using a query: 'SELECT TIMEZONE(TO_DATE(Value1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') , Value2 , Value3) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WHERE Value1=ORCHESTRATE.INPUTDATE and Value2=ORCHESTRATE.SourceT AND
Value3=ORCHESTRATE.TargetT' . The function as you see takes 3 arguments. I would like to pass them from transformer. To be continued..:)

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher , If I have 100 input records, I would like to return the result of scalar function 100 times. Now I'm receiving many warning and errors, for example: 'Lookup_0: Unable to determine association between statement parameters and table columns. The connector will not be able to obtain external schema and only limited schema reconciliation will be performed' or

Comment: or 'Lookup_0,1: SQLExecute reported: SQLSTATE = 42S22: Native Error Code = -206: Msg = [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXOOP11] SQL0206N  "VALUE1" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703 (CC_DB2DBStatement::executeSelect, file CC_DB2DBStatement.cpp, line 2,095)'.  How do I pass arguments from the transformer to the built-in scalar function? As I said, because some internal restrictions I cannot use stored procedures. In my example I used Peek as a target but  after testing I need to replace with txt file.